# how can change settings, as this example?

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to change the location settings as the example attached a screenshot.
This makes it from google maps and if I press If default is set, high precision mode.
Then how can do it?

[image]

Comment: I think that this is explicitly described in the docs for GPS on Android.

Comment: @zgc7009 what is this documents?